# What should users of 32-bit use instead of Tensorflow lib?

Tags: library, python, machine-learning

When I wanted to started to make machine learning programs using python and libraries such as Tensorflow, I faced a big problem! I couldn't install Tensor flow on my Windows 7 **32-bit** computer.

Is there any other library instead of Tensorflow (but like this library) for machine learning programs? Can you help me?

Note: I use python 3.6

Comment: I know it's kind of backwards, but you might want to think about upgrading your computer. For something like Tensorflow, there's not enough call for 32 bit versions for it to be worth maintaining them.

Comment: Adding to Michael Kohne's comment, getting a modern computer would net you 256-bit FPU support and a bunch of other performance benefits even aside from being able to just use Tensorflow.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations SE, alilolo!  Can you please provide a few details about the functionality you need from the library?